# Why is A intersection A' null?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intersection between 2 sets means the elements that are common to both those sets. I read that at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).

$\varnothing$ is the subset of every set but not an element of all the sets.

**If $\varnothing$ is not an element of every set, then why is A intersection A' = null?**

Edit: I just started reading sets. I had this doubt and I asked it. Sorry I might have done something wrong but please don't be angry at me.

Suppose A = {1,3,5} and U = {1,2,3,4,5} So A' = {2,4}. So why will A intersection A' = null, when null is not an element of any of the two sets (A and A')?

Comment: This question barely makes sense; what is $A^\prime$? If what is an element of every set?

Comment: For the proof that $\emptyset$ is subset of every set, see the post : [empty-set-subsets-and-vacuous-truths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721368/empty-set-subsets-and-vacuous-truths).

Comment: What you call "null" is the [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) : it is **not** listed between the elements of $A = \{ 1,3,5 \}$ and thus $\emptyset \notin A$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So yes empty set is not in set A, so if it is not an element of neither A nor A', why is A intersection A' = empty set?

Comment: Two sets are *equal* exactly when they have the same elements. $\emptyset$ is empty: i.e. it has **no** elements. We have shown that $A \cap A'$ has **no** elements (because there are no common elements to a set and its complement). Thus, the two sets: $A \cap A'$ and $\emptyset$ are equal, because both have **no** elements.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you. thank you. I understand now. Thank you. Sorry but should I delete this question or let it be? Or can you post that as an answer so that I can ✅ it?

Comment: Related, possibly helpful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620616/what-is-the-difference-between-x-and-x-when-x-itself-is-a-set/2620621#2620621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the definition of [Complement (of a set)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Definition), denoted : $A^c,\overline A,A′$.

If $A′$ is the complement of the set $A$, obviously $A \cap A′= \emptyset$, because from $x ∈ A \cap A′$ we have that $x∈A$ and $x∈A′$.

The last one is equivalent to $x∉A$, and thus we have bot $x∈A$ and $x∉A$ : contradicition !

Thus there are **no** common elements to $A$ and $A'$, i.e. their intersection $A \cap A'$ is empty.

Two sets are *equal* exactly when they have the same elements.

$\emptyset$ is empty: i.e. it has **no** elements.

We have shown that $A \cap A′$ has **no** elements (because there are no common elements to a set and its complement).

Thus, the two sets: $A \cap A′$ and $\emptyset$ are equal, because both have **no** elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation yet, otherwise I'd add this as a comment.

Subsets are not the same things as elements, so although $\emptyset$ is a subset of both $A$ and its complement, whether or not it is an element depends on what exactly is contained in $A$. If it is an element of $A$ it will not be an element of $A$'s complement.

Related: [Is empty set element of every set if it is subset of every set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103664/is-empty-set-element-of-every-set-if-it-is-subset-of-every-set)
and
[Is the null set a subset of every set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528630/is-the-null-set-a-subset-of-every-set)

Comment: Suppose A = { 1,2,3} and U = {1,2,3,4}. So A' = {4}. So will then A intersection A' = null? If yes, why? Null is not an element of any set here.

Comment: I would rather say: subsets of some set $A$ are not the same things as elements of $A$. This because in set-theory subsets and elements are both sets (so in that sense the same thing).

Comment: @RamKeswani If you are saying that $A\cap A^{\complement}=\varnothing$ then you are not saying at all that $\varnothing\in A\cap A^{\complement}$. The only thing you are saying is that $A\cap A^{\complement}$ **has no elements**.